# delphi how to create and assign a stack

Tags: oop, delphi, stack, var

I am really struggling with this and can't find anything online about it - or I might not be understand what is written online. I am trying to create a stack and use ibut I can't even create it.

I am creating it in a procedure and I want the stack to contain integers. I have tried to following and I just get the red line underneath (both are in the var section of the procedure):

genericstack:TObjectStack;
as well as
genericstack:TStack;

and neither have worked in setting the stack. I just get an red line underneath.

Comment: Forget about red lines. Include compiler error I your question.

Comment: Could it be that you are not including the unit that actually defines these types? If not, add it (put *System.Generics.Collections* in your `uses` clause, and if you have no such clause, add it at the right place).

Answer (score 1):

you may check example code in official site:
[Generics Collections TObjectStack](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/Generics_Collections_TObjectStack_(Delphi))

useful one:
[How to store a String in a TObjectStack](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/e5/524140.html)

and also
[FlowPanel example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FlowPanels_(Delphi))

and a snippet may fit as your answer:

```
{
This example demonstrates the usage of the generic TObjectStack class.
}
type
  { Declare a new object type }
  TNewObject = class
  private
    FName: String;

  public
    constructor Create(const AName: String);
    destructor Destroy(); override;
  end;

{ TNewObject }

constructor TNewObject.Create(const AName: String);
begin
  FName := AName;
end;

destructor TNewObject.Destroy;
begin
  { Show a message whenever an object is destroyed }
  MessageDlg('Object "' + FName + '" was destroyed!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stack: TObjectStack<TNewObject>;
  Button: TButton;
begin
  { Create a new stack }
  Stack := TObjectStack<TNewObject>.Create();

  { Set the OwnsObjects to true - the stack will free them automatically }
  Stack.OwnsObjects := true;

  { Push some items up the stack }
  Stack.Push(TNewObject.Create('One'));
  Stack.Push(TNewObject.Create('Two'));
  Stack.Push(TNewObject.Create('Three'));

  {
    Pop an instance of TNewObject class. Destructor
    show be called because we have set the OwnsObjects
    to true!
  }
  Stack.Pop();

  { Destroy the stack completely - more messageboxes will be shown }
  Stack.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Do I need to add the constucctor and destoryer? C not just create the class in var? Also I have written TObjectstack<integer> but it still has the red line underneath.

Comment: Have you included System.Generics.Collections in your uses clause?

Comment: @Rosie: these are called *constructor* and *destructor*. If you declare an object like `TNewObject`, and the class contains objects that must be freed, you must usually have these too. ISTM that you should start reading the Delphi (or Object Pascal) language guide, that comes in the built-in help [or on the web](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Delphi_Language_Guide_Index).

Comment: Forget the red lines.. some of those appear when they shouldn't. The important thing is whether your app compiles.